# "Failed to decode response from marionette" message in Python/Firefox headless scraping script

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, web-scraping, geckodriver

Good Day, I've done a number of searches on here and google and yet to find a solution that address this problem.

The scenario is:

I have a Python script (2.7) that loops through an number of URLs (e.g. think Amazon pages, scraping reviews).  Each page has the same HTML layout, just scraping different information.  I use Selenium with a headless browser as these pages have javascript that needs to execute to grab the information.

I run this script on my local machine (OSX 10.10).  Firefox is the latest v59.  Selenium is version at 3.11.0 and using geckodriver v0.20.

This script locally has no issues, it can run through all the URLs and scrape the pages with no issue.

Now when I put the script on my server, the only difference is it is Ubuntu 16.04 (32 bit).  I use the appropriate geckodriver (still v0.20) but everything else is the same (Python 2.7, Selenium 3.11).  It appears to randomly crash the headless browser and then all of the `browserObjt.get('url...')` no longer work.

The error messages say:

> Message: failed to decode response from marionette

Any further selenium requests for pages return the error:

> Message: tried to run command without establishing a connection

---

To show some code:

When I create the driver:

```
    options = Options()
    options.set_headless(headless=True)

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(
        firefox_options=options,
        executable_path=config.GECKODRIVER
    )
```

`driver` is passed to the script's function as a parameter `browserObj` which is then used to call specific pages and then once that loads it is passed to BeautifulSoup for parsing:

```
browserObj.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browserObj.page_source, 'lxml')
```

---

The error might be pointing to the BeautifulSoup line which is crashing the browser.

What is likely causing this, and what can I do to resolve the issue?

---

Edit: Adding stack trace which points to the same thing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 164, in <module>
    getLeague
  File "/home/ps/dataparsing/XXX/yyy.py", line 48, in BBB
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browserObj.page_source, 'lxml')
  File "/home/ps/AAA/projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 670, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
  File "/home/ps/AAA/projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ps/AAA/projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette
```

---

Note: This script used to work with Chrome.  Because the server is a 32bit server, I can only use chromedriver v0.33, which only supports Chrome v60-62.  Currently Chrome is v65 and on DigitalOcean I don't seem to have an easy way to revert back to an old version - which is why I am stuck with Firefox.

Comment: Update the question with error stack trace.

Comment: Added stack trace per request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I still don't know why this is happening but I may have found a work around.  I read in some documentation there may be a race condition (on what, I am not sure since there shouldn't be two items competing for the same resources).

I changed the scraping code to do this:

```
import time

browserObj.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browserObj.page_source, 'lxml')
```

No specific reason why I chose 3 seconds but since adding this delay I have not had the `Message: failed to decode response from marionette` error from any of my list of URLs to scrape.

---

**Update: October, 2018**

This continues to be an issue over six months later.  Firefox, Geckodriver, Selenium and PyVirtualDisplay have all been updated to their latest versions.  This error kept reoccurring spontaneously without pattern: sometimes working and sometimes not.

What fixed this issue is increasing RAM on my server from 1 GB to 2 GB.  Since the increase there have been no failures of this sort.

Comment: Is your issue fixed?. I am also getting same error randomly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831841/python-selenium-failing-on-same-function-on-2nd-time

Comment: Probably because of this [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1198459)

Comment: I was plagued with this for a while before I discovered a way to do a proper wait on the DOM. See my answer if you haven't fixed this yet. Hope it helps!

Comment: Confirming that increasing the RAM on my Droplet instance from 1GB to 2GB also solved this.

Comment: Still getting this error even with 4gb ram..

Answer (score 43):

For anyone else experiencing this issue when running selenium webdriver in a Docker container, [increasing the container size to 2gb](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/pull/485/files#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R43) fixes [this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1338771#c10).

I guess this affects physical machines too if the OP fixed their issue by upgrading their server RAM to 2Gb, but could be coincidence.

Comment: If there was a way to give you more than one upvote, I am in! Spent hours on figuring this out! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly my problem. Apparently, the [default is only 64mb...](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Comment: I run into such problem while trying to do full content screenshot, by `window.resize_to` and then `driver.screenshot_as` , on how larger could i scale a browser window, "free ram" seems relavent as you stated.

Comment: That's awesome!

Comment: Thank you so much, i would have been stuck for a long time

Comment: Another tip if you are running docker-compose is to set `shm_size: 2gb` under your browser service.

Answer (score 8):

This error message...

```
Message: failed to decode response from marionette
```

...implies that the communication between *GeckoDriver* and *Marionette* was interrupted/broken.

---

Some of the reasons and solution for this issue are as follows:

- In the discussion [Crash during command execution results in "Internal Server Error: Failed to decode response from marionette"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1401131) @whimboo mentions, while executing your tests [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) may force a crash of the parent process of Firefox with an error as:

  ```
  DEBUG   <- 500 Internal Server Error {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Failed to decode response from marionette","stacktrace":...}...}
  ```

  - Analysis: The current message is somewhat misleading and Geckdriver needs to handle this situation and reporting that the application has unexpectedly quit, in a better way. This issue is still open.
- In the discussion [Failed to decode response from marionette with Firefox >= 65](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1560) @rafagonc mentioned, this issue can occur when using *GeckoDriver* / [FirefoxDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996626/is-this-correct-firefoxdriver-driver-new-firefoxdriver/49996820#49996820) or [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) in docker environment, due to presence of [Zombie process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) that hangs even after invoking `driver.quit()`. At times, when you open many browsing instances one after another, your system may run out of memory or out of PIDs. See: [Selenium using too much RAM with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072731/selenium-using-too-much-ram-with-firefox/55075243#55075243)

  - As a solution @andreastt mentions, the following configuration should resolve the out of memory issue with Docker:

    ```
    --memory 1024mb --shm-size 2g
    ```

> **Steps**: Configure [SHM size in the docker container](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#running-the-images)

- Similarly, while executing your test in your localhost, it is advisable to keep the following (minimum) configuration:

  ```
  --memory 1024mb
  ```

---

### Additional Considerations

This issue can also occur due to **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

Solution:

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [JDK 8u341](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [GeckoDriver v0.26.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0) level.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to *Firefox v72.0* levels.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.

---

### [*GeckoDriver*, *Selenium* and *Firefox Browser* compatibility chart](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html)

[image: GeckoDriverVersions]

---

### tl; dr

[[e10s] Crash in libyuv::ARGBSetRow_X86](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1338771)

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Browsing context has been discarded using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525301/browsing-context-has-been-discarded-using-geckodriver-firefox-through-selenium/54529774#54529774)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you do not close the driver. I made the same mistake. Whit htop in Linux, I have noticed that I occupy all the 26 GB of my pc whit firefox unclosed process.

Comment: Yes! This was the problem for me too, I noticed there were a lot of geckodriver.exe processes still running so killing them fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The likely real issue behind this is that the DOM has not loaded yet and you are triggering searches on the next page. That's why the `sleep(3)` is working in most cases. The proper fix is to use a wait class.

This is an example test case using a wait function for Nextcloud. It's from my docker-selenium-firefox-python image: https://hub.docker.com/r/nowsci/selenium

Notice how the `wait` class is called surrounding any `click` or `get` calls. Basically, what this does is takes advantage of the fact that selenium changes the ID for the `HTML` tag on page load. The wait function checks if the new ID is different than the old, and when it is, the DOM has loaded.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class wait(object):

    def __init__(self, browser):
        self.browser = browser

    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_page = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html')

    def page_has_loaded(self):
        new_page = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
        return new_page.id != self.old_page.id

    def __exit__(self, *_):
        start_time = time.time()
        while time.time() < start_time + 5:
            if self.page_has_loaded():
                return True
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        raise Exception('Timeout waiting for page load.')

def test():
    try:
        opts = Options()
        opts.headless = True
        assert opts.headless  # Operating in headless mode
        browser = Firefox(options=opts)
    except Exception as e:
        print("  -=- FAIL -=-: Browser setup - ", e)
        return

    # Test title
    try:
        with wait(browser):
            browser.get('https://nextcloud.mydomain.com/index.php/login')
        assert 'Nextcloud' in browser.title
    except Exception as e:
        print("  -=- FAIL -=-: Initial load - ", e)
        return
    else:
        print("  Success: Initial load")

    try:
        # Enter user
        elem = browser.find_element_by_id('user')
        elem.send_keys("MYUSER")

        # Enter password
        elem = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
        elem.send_keys("MYPASSWORD")

        # Submit form
        elem = browser.find_element_by_id('submit')
        with wait(browser):
            elem.click()

        # Check title for success
        assert 'Files' in browser.title
    except Exception as e:
        print("  -=- FAIL -=-: Login - ", e)
        return
    else:
        print("  Success: Login")

    print("  Finished.")

print("Testing nextcloud...")
test()
```

Combine this with the answer from @myol if you are using Docker.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this saves some other poor soul the hours I just spent on this.

[Download an old version of firefox](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) (specifically, v66 for me), and point selenium there:

```
firefox_binary='/home/user/Downloads/old_firefox/firefox/firefox'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, for **Ubuntu 16.04**:

1. Install `firefox`

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firefox
```

2. Check that `firefox` is well installed

```sh
which firefox
```

Will return `/usr/bin/firefox`

3. Go to the `geckodriver` releases page. Find the latest version of the driver for your platform and download it. For example:

```sh
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz
```

4. Extract the file with:

```sh
tar -xvzf geckodriver*
```

5. Make it executable:

```sh
chmod +x geckodriver
```

6. Move it to `$PATH` and give `root` access

```sh
sudo mv geckodriver /usr/bin/
cd /usr/bin
sudo chown root:root geckodriver
```

7. Install `selenium`

```sh
pip3 install selenium
```

8. Add `firefox` and `geckodriver` to `$PATH`

```sh
sudo vim ~/.bashrc
```

Add the two lines:

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:"/usr/bin/firefox"
export PATH=$PATH:"/usr/bin/geckodriver"
```

9. **Reboot** your instance

```sh
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 2):

This error may be caused by starting the browser too many times without properly closing it.

In case of the OP's Python code `driver.quit()` should be called after either successful or failed run. All exceptions must be caught.

No matter how much memory you system has, if the browser is not properly closed, subsequent runs will eventually make it impossible to start yet another one. In that case adding more memory would only postpone that moment.

1. To check for orphaned browser processes use `ps aux` command on Linux (or in Powershell on Windows).
2. To kill such processes use `killall firefox` command or `killall firefox-esr` when using Firefox Extended Support Release). This might require sudo.

*References:*

- https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/windows/#quitting-the-browser-at-the-end-of-a-session
- https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/index.html?highlight=quit#example-1

Comment: The zombie firefox processes here turned out to be the cause for me; the Ubuntu 18.04 box had 200 zombie firefox processes running, and killing them allowed selenium to start successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem in Windows 11 (Message: failed to decode response from marionette). In my case, changing the class I was looking for in the code snippet helped:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,
        'et_pb_row_10')))
```

The above code is already after the change.