# Is this correct - FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have seen almost everybody using the statement `WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();` here we have created an instance of `FirefoxDriver` class having type as `Webdriver`; 
What if i directly create an instance of FirefoxDriver as `FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`
I have gone through many discussion where it is said that Webdriver is an interface. I know what interface is and how it works. I want to know if  `FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` is correct when i know that Firefox is the only browser i am gonna use in my selenium script?

Comment: It is correct if you want to use a `FirefoxDriver` specifically, for example to access firefox-specific methods. If you just want to access a `WebDriver` generally (for example you want the same tests to run against Firefox, Chrome etc - perhaps not now, but in the future maybe), use `WebDriver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question that *know that **Firefox** is the only browser you are gonna use in your selenium script* then there is no constraint in using the following line of code :

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [What is the difference between ChromeDriver and WebDriver in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871)