# Kill GeckoDriver by PID Process [Java]

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, process, pid, geckodriver

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793476/kill-selenium-browser-by-pid-process-java). I launch many instances of `WebDriver` and some of them don't respond to `driver.quit()`. As described in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57804371/10809264) I am able to kill browser instance by retrieving PID *directly* from capabilities object via the following code:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

  public class Kill_Firefox_PID {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
          System.out.println("moz:processID value is : "+cap.getCapability("moz:processID"));
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /PID "+cap.getCapability("moz:processID"));
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  moz:processID value is : 8492
  ```

While this works excellently to kill browser itself I still see instances of `Geckodriver` when I open task manager. As stated in the other thread I am unable to indiscriminately kill all `Geckdriver` instances via `taskkill /f /im geckodriver.exe` as there are some instances that are needed.

In short, I want to be able to retrieve PID of `Geckodriver` via capabilities and destroy those instances of `Geckodriver` (via PID) in a similar way that we are able to retrieve PID of `Firefox WebDriver` as outlined [in response to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793476/kill-selenium-browser-by-pid-process-java).

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A new set of *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox Browser* are initiated when you invoke:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Is this correct - FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996626/is-this-correct-firefoxdriver-driver-new-firefoxdriver/49996820#49996820)

---

The life span of *GeckoDriver* / *Firefox Browser* ceases to exist when you invoke:

```
driver.quit()
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)

---

### Solution

So a generic solution would be, instead of keeping the keeping/preserving the stale instances of [geckodriver](/questions/tagged/geckodriver) invoke **`close()`** or **`quit()`** as per the flow of your test execution which will relieve you from indiscriminately killing all the *GeckoDriver* instances.

However at the end of your *Test Execution* if you want to kill all the *GeckoDriver* instances, you can use the following solution:

```
public class Killing_GeckoDriver_PID {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String line;
        String pidInfo ="";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
        BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            pidInfo+=line; 
        }
        input.close();

        if(pidInfo.contains("geckodriver.exe"))
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM geckodriver.exe"); 
        }
        System.out.println("Killed all the instances of GeckoDriver");
    }
}
```

> You can find a alternative approach within the discussion [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)