# WebDriverException: Failed to decode response from marionette

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, headless

I am trying to run headless Firefox on AWS Codebuild linux. I am using selenium 3.6, gecko-driver 0.21.0, Firefox version 61.0.2. When I run the tests locally everything works fine, when I run it on Codebuild I get an error. The error on line 126 is when I am trying to click on an element. My code:

```
public static WebDriver getFirefoxHeadless(Map map) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/root/firefox_driver/geckodriver");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = 
        DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setHeadless(true);

        GeckoDriverService service;
        GeckoDriverService.Builder builder = new 
        GeckoDriverService.Builder();
        service = builder.usingAnyFreePort()
                .withEnvironment(map)
                .build();

        service.start();

        options.merge(capabilities);

        return new FirefoxDriver(service, options);
    }

@BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        driver = Helpers.getFirefoxHeadless(MozLog.getMozLogMap());
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));

        driver.get(getUrl());
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }

    @Test
    public void clickoutTestFirefox() throws IOException, InterruptedException, SQLException {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".popup-close-button-slim")).click();
```

I get the following error on Codebuild run:

com.clickout.apitesting.waUITest.E2ECNTestFirefox.clickoutTestFirefox FAILED
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to decode response from marionette
    Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
    System info: host: 'ip-172-32-0-217.eu-west-1.compute.internal', ip: '172.32.0.217', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.59-64.43.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
    Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 62.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: true, moz:processID: 2393, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofile.AD0yj8..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 4.14.59-64.43.amzn1.x86_64, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
    Session ID: f0ea1950-77fe-463b-a8a1-e0dc5458800f
    *** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=.popup-close-button-slim}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:416)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:431)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:314)
        at com.clickout.apitesting.waUITest.E2ECNTestFirefox.clickoutTestFirefox(E2ECNTestFirefox.java:126)

Comment: No direct solution but here the OP said increasing RAM solved the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734915/failed-to-decode-response-from-marionette-message-in-python-firefox-headless-s