# Failed to Decode Response from Marionette in selenium using geckodriver and Freebsd

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

i have problem with reading data with selenium.
In my pc working code fine, with microsoft edge. But then i get task set up it on freebsd.
So i try to use geckodriver now its working with firefox.

`Firefox version 83`, `geckodriver 0.26.0`, with 0.28 version i got error `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error:`

So now im getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "skriptas.py", line 21, in <module>
    obj.testmethod()
  File "skriptas.py", line 17, in testmethod
    allheader=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(expected.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li[class='result-item'] .result-name-area>.result-name")))
  File "/home/MyUserName/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "/home/MyUserName/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 189, in __call__
    elements = _find_elements(driver, self.locator)
  File "/home/MyUserName/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 422, in _find_elements
    raise e
  File "/home/MyUserName/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 420, in _find_elements
    return driver.find_elements(*by)
  File "/home/MyUserName/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1007, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "/home/MyUserName/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/MyUserName/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette
```

my code

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expected
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


class runTest():
    def testmethod(self):
        path='/home/MyUserName/skriptas/forGeckodriver/geckodriver'

        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('-headless')
        driver = Firefox(executable_path=path, options=options)
        driver.get("https://www.verivox.de/stromvergleich/vergleich/#/?plz=10555&persons=on&usage=3500&bonus=OnlyCompliant&profile=H0&product=electricity&source=1&q=WzYsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMiwyMCwwLDEsNzQxMTIyLCI3MTA4NSIsMSwyNDAsMjQwLDM1MDAsMCwwLDAsOTk5LC0xLC0xLC0xLDAsMCwiVG90YWxDb3N0cyIsIkFzY2VuZGluZyIsIk5vbmUiLDM4LCJBbm51YWxDb3N0VmlldyIsMF0%3D&partnerid=1")
        allheader=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(expected.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li[class='result-item'] .result-name-area>.result-name")))
        for header in allheader:
            print("Header: " + header.text)
obj = runTest()
obj.testmethod()
```

Any know where is problem? Please help me, im stuck right now

EDITED
Add geckodriver.log

```
1606147335757   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/local/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileJmvJgF"
*** You are running in headless mode.
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: Cc[aContract] is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
1606147376842   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 54093
1606147378900   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
1606156761595   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/local/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile4c8wsu"
*** You are running in headless mode.
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: Cc[aContract] is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
1606156799481   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 11622
1606156803889   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
1606156945032   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/local/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileJ99d7Z"
*** You are running in headless mode.
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: Cc[aContract] is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
1606156976247   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 35003
1606156978342   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
1606206490143   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/local/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileiprRHB"
*** You are running in headless mode.
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: Cc[aContract] is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
1606206545550   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 40209
1606206554386   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
JavaScript error: , line 0: uncaught exception: Object
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
1606207117587   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/local/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileqKfzHk"
*** You are running in headless mode.
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: Cc[aContract] is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
console.warn: services.settings: Could not determine network status. Message: TypeError: gNetworkLinkService is undefined
1606207165342   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 57742
1606207167633   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
```

Comment: Check this answer. See If this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734915/failed-to-decode-response-from-marionette-message-in-python-firefox-headless-s

Comment: like you see    ```allheader=WebDriverWait(driver,20)``` this is for waiting time. So this link not help for me. And i try with ```import time```

Comment: @Kalakutas Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734915/failed-to-decode-response-from-marionette-message-in-python-firefox-headless-s/60178324#60178324) helps you?

Comment: It not help me.