# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to decode response from marionette

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I am executing my test cases in selenium (3.141.59) in Intellj with Firefox 119 and geckodriver-v0.33.0-win64. Test cases keep failing. Firefox browser just starts and terminates with doing anything with below error. Can anyone suggest any solution?

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to decode response from marionette
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
```

Tried with changing multiple combination of selenium versions and Firefox with gecko driver.

Comment: Check this question/answers if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734915/failed-to-decode-response-from-marionette-message-in-python-firefox-headless-s

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.